# ¿Se puede almacenar el valor de una variable de JavaScript en un value de un input?

Tags: javascript, variables, input

creen que puedan poner el valor de la variable operation en la misma caja de taxto donde ingresamos las operaciones ejemplo si agrego 2+2 quiero que el valor (4) se almacene el value del input.

```js
            function calc() {

            //Coger el valor del input
            var value = document.getElementById("pizarra").value;

            //Operar los datos recogidos
            var operation = eval(value); 
            document.getElementById('resul').innerHTML = operation;
}
```

```html
<input name="display" value="" type="text" id="pizarra"> = <label id="resul"></label>
<input type="button" onclick="calc()" value="calcular">
```

Comment: document.getElementsByName('display').value = valor_a_pasarle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que se puede. Lo que tendrías que hacer sería lo siguiente:

```
document.getElementById('pizarra').value = operation
```

Solo dos cosas:

1. Evita poner funciones de JS directamente en los elementos html.
2. También evita usar eval() como método para sumar ambos valores

Aquí puedes encontrar algo de información de eval. --> https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

Espero te sirva!.